# cloudera manager fails to start services after upgrade to 5.10

Tags: hibernate, cloudera, cloudera-manager

After upgrading cloudera manager to 5.10, it fails to start all services with this message in the WebUI :

> org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Exception occurred inside setter of com.cloudera.cmf.model.DbProcess.resourcesForDb

Started services (hdfs, yarn, hive, etc..) are in status `STARTING`, and they work well. But for the manager it looks like it failed to start.
When looking in the manager DB, the status is in 'STARTING' instead of `RUNNING`, but it looks like it's the only step missing to make everything work.

The manager DB is an external PostgreSQL 8.4

Comment: Did you inspect the log files of the Cloudera Manager service, somewhere in `/var/log/`? And did you check the Cloudera forum? *[disclaimer - I would be happy if that bug could be reported & solved before I have to run that upgrade myself, because I've had my share of bug reports...]*

Comment: Yes, I've been watching at every log files and googling for hours now, but no luck. (edit: hours > 24)

Comment: After trying everything, rolled back to 5.9.1 and everything works.